# What datastructure to quickly map multiple objects to another object

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I need a different datastructure for my application.

Essentially I have a custom data structure consisting of "nodes".
My task is as follows:
Given a number of distinct nodes (where the number of nodes I get is unknown) retrieve or create a new node. It reminds me very much of a cache for a function with multiple arguments. The only difference is that all arguments and the return value have the same type and values I returned might be given to me as input later on.

*Example 1*:
At first I get nodes A and C. Now I have to create a new node (lets name it AC) and return it.
When I get the nodes A and C *again* in the future I need to be able to **very quickly** determine if I have already created the AC node and return it, or, if it has not been created before, create it and return it.

*Example 2*:
When I get the nodes C and A then I have to return/create a different node! I cannot return AC, it has to be a new node (CA). Order is important!

Later in processing it's also possible that I will get nodes I created earlier.
For example in the third call to my datastructure it's entirely possible that I receive the nodes "A and AC". Again I have to create a new node "A-AC", cache it and return it.

At first I used many `Dictionary<Tuple<Node, Node>, Node>` but this has multiple problems:
 - Creating and comparing with tuples turned out to be too slow for my application
 - The number of arguments is fixed, I need multiple dictionaries each with a different key (2-tuples, 3-tuples, ...)

I also have a lot of nodes. I am already filtering the incoming data a bit but I will have to process at least 15 million to 20 million different nodes.

A dictionary doesn't seem to cut it, performance as well as memory consumption seem to be too high.

I can freely modify how the nodes are implemented so maybe there is another trick I can use to directly link many nodes to another one?

How can I solve this problem as efficiently as possible?
What datastructure is used for this problem usually?

Comment: Does Node contain a field/property with above name like "A", "C", "AC" "A-AC"?

Comment: No, unfortunately the nodes do not contain a 'name' or other identifier. The numeric content 'payload' of the nodes also changes too much in order to be useful to idenfify it. There is no way to idenfify a single node other than having a reference to it. I thought about giving them all a string-name but unfortunately that consumes way too much memory with the amount of nodes I have to work.

Comment: Can you give us some more insight on what exactly these nodes are and why you cant uniquely ID them? Im thinking about making some sorta hashing function

Comment: Of course it would be possible to add a unique ID (32bit or 64bit) to each node. But how would I apply that to solve my problem?
If your idea of adding a unique ID to the nodes indeed solves the problem then maybe it's possible to use the reference/address directly so I can save memory?

Comment: *Again I have to create a new node "A-AC", cache it and return it* - Is there ever a possibility that you will have to get or add a combination of nodes that is not 2? All your cases you listed seem to look like A and C, C and A, A and AC etc. Would there ever be [A, C, A] => AC-A? Or [B, C, A] => B-C-A ?

Comment: Yes that is a very real possibility. I only used single and double nodes so the examples dont get too complex. I have to point out that in your example "A,C,A" should result in the "ACA" node (like your B,C,A example) and "AC-A" can only be produced by "AC,A"! It's possible that every source-node can be combined with every created-node. So all combinations are possible. Example [AC, B, FXY] => [AC-B-FXY]. That means the node AC, which was created by A and C, is used together with B and FXY to form a entirely new node "AC-B-FXY"...

Comment: @Felheart hmm ya I get it. Seems you have got ur answer. Kindly tag ppl like I did: "@Fellheart". Only then ppl are notified.

Comment: @nawfal I wasn't aware of that, thank you. I'll make use of the @ feature in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a lot of constraints (time, efficiency, memory footprint). To be honest, I'm not sure where you put the bar for those constraints.

I once created a small data structure that accomplishes something similar to what you want. I think.

```
public class StackBlock
{
    public string Component { get; set; }
    public MyObject ResultingObject { get; set; }
    public List<StackBlock> Blocks { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that you use these to construct a tree that functions as a cache for your already created objects. A small description of what the properties do:

- Component is where you would store your `"A"` or `"C"` value
- ResultingObject is your cached item `"AC"`
- Blocks is what you use to create chains of blocks.

So if you wanted to store your `"AC"` object, this would be structure you save it in:

```
StackBlock
    Component: "A"
    ResultingObject: null
    Blocks: [
                StackBlock
                    Component: "C"
                    ResultingObject: MyObject "AC"
                    Blocks: [ ... ]
            ]
```

**Edit** Very simply put, item "CGA" will be found in:

```
StackBlock "C" -> StackBlock "G" -> StackBlock "A" -> ResultingItem
```

You can keep stacking blocks together to make longer and longer combinations. But when you need to retrieve an object, all you have to do is traverse the tree in order:

- Find StackBlock A.
- In StackBlock A, find child Stackblock C.
- In child StackBlock C, look at the ResultingObject. If it is not null, return the cached object.

Note that for every step, if you cannot find what you are looking for, that means it was not yet created, so you must create the object and *then store it in the tree*. The next time you request it, it will now be available.

In your case, "AC" and "CA" are different objects, and the tree allows you to store these in separate locations.

This will also ensure you don't create an object when it was already in memory, *because the tree structure only allows for a single place to put a specific element*.

I hope this is somewhat in the direction you want?

*Note: This is a very old project of mine, before LINQ was introduced. I can only imagine that the resulting code is rather elegant and concise when you use LINQ for traversing the tree. I'll spare you how I used to do it.*

**Answer to the below comment**

If you have item "GA" and item "CGA", they will not be part of the **same** StackBlock "A".
If you've already cached those two objects, the tree will be as follows:

```
StackBlock C
    -> StackBlock G
        -> StackBlock A
            -> ResultingObject CGA        
StackBlock G
    -> StackBlock A
        -> ResultingObject GA
```

*Note: You'd be storing the upper elements in a List. From that list, you find the first element and start drilling down.*

One possible point of confusion I'd like to address: You see two Stackblocks "G" and two StackBlocks "A". **These are not the same objects**. Every stackblock you see mentioned in all my examples are different objects (that just happen to have the same letter).

*Maybe it'd be better to understand if you define StackBlock as a struct instead of a class. It'd work just the same, and you're prevented from reusing the same StackBlock on different tiers of the tree you're constructing.*

ResultingObject should therefore not be a list, because there should only be a single object that we call "CGA". The entire point of the exercise is to prevent a duplicate object being created, so this data structure is specifically tailored to only allow one place to put your cached object.

Maybe it helps if I flesh out the example, so you can see where everything would end up:

```
StackBlock C
    -> StackBlock G        
        -> ResultingObject CG
        -> StackBlock A
            -> ResultingObject CGA  
        -> StackBlock B
            -> ResultingObject CGB

StackBlock G
    -> ResultingObject G
    -> StackBlock A
        -> ResultingObject GA
        -> StackBlock X
            -> ResultingObject GAX
            -> StackBlock K
                -> ResultingObject GAXK
```

Look at the two Stackblocks called "G". One of them is on the top level, so its ResultingObject is simply G. But the other one is a second-level StackBlock. Therefore, its ResultingObject is CG, because *you have to account for the entire chain you drilled down*.

I hope this helped clear it up. It's a simple concept once you understand it, but I'm having some difficulty describing why this works :)

Comment: "item "CGA" will be found in:..." Ok, lets assume I'm looking for the node constructed by "C,G,A". I take the C node, then I look trough all "blocks" in C to find the G node, then that again to get from G to A. So A.ResultingObject will be CGA. Then where is the object GA (for the input "G,A") saved? Is it also saved in A?? So should resultingObject rather be a list? CGA and GA are different objects for me, so they can't be saved at the same position. I hope my question is clear, if not please ask.

Comment: No, the beginning of the string is the beginning of the list. Let me update my question as it allows for better formatting. Give me two minutes :)

Comment: @Felheart: I updated the question. The key part here is that a second-tier StackBlock will always have a two-letter-combination ("GA") as a ResultingObject. A third-tier stackblock will always have a three-letter-combination as a ResultingObjects (e.g. "GAC")

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect example of when to use a digital search tree also know as a Trie. Basically each Node has an array of nodes and a null node. As you work your way down the tree as in example 1 to A then to C if that C node make a reference to the null node then you know that you have already loaded that node. if it does not then it hasn't been loaded yet. I don't think that there are any built in implementations of a trie but they are not that hard to build. I built one once to store the english dictionary and used it to check to to see if words existed. If you build it correctly it takes up next to no space in memory and will have access time of O(1).